# Components of an $(k,l)$-tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

I'm watching [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4l-qzZOZt50) by Frederic Schuller on YouTube trying to understand the structure of the vector space $T^k_l(V)=\underbrace{V^* \otimes \dots \otimes V^*}_{l} \otimes \underbrace{V \otimes \dots \otimes V}_{k}$ and I have some difficulties with the components.

If $(e_1, \dots ,e_n)$ is a basis for $V$ and $(\epsilon^1, \dots, \epsilon^n)$ is the dual basis for $V^*$, then the basis for $T^k_l(V)$ is of the form $$e_{j_1} \otimes \dots \otimes e_{j_l} \otimes \epsilon^{i_1} \otimes \dots \otimes \epsilon^{i_k}.$$

Now any tensor $F \in T^k_l(V)$ can be written in the form $$F=F^{j_1 \dots j_l}_{i_1 \dots i_k}e_{j_1} \otimes \dots \otimes e_{j_l} \otimes \epsilon^{i_1} \otimes \dots \otimes \epsilon^{i_k}$$ where $F^{j_1 \dots j_l}_{i_1 \dots i_k}=F(\epsilon^{j_1}, \dots, \epsilon^{j_l}, \dots e_{i_1}, \dots, e_{i_k}).$

---

I'm trying to verify this by computation, but I don't yet get it right. Given vectors $a_1, \dots, a_k$ and covectors $b^1, \dots, b^l$ I should be able to start computing from $$F(b^1, \dots, b^l, a_1, \dots,a^k)$$ but I'm stuck in how I can express $b^i$ as a linear combination of the dual basis vectors. I think I have that $b^i = b^1\epsilon^1 + \dots +b^n\epsilon^n$, but now I'm having issues with the indexes as $b^i$ represents a covector and at the same time a scalar component of the covector.

Is there some way around this as I cannot figure this out with the indexes here?

Comment: Why are you evaluating $F(b^1,\dots,b^l,a_1,\dots,a_k)$? Given that elements of the form $e_{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{j_l}\otimes\epsilon^{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes\epsilon^{i_k}$ constitute a basis, you know that $F = A_{i_1\dots i_k}^{j_1\dots j_l}e_{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{j_l}\otimes\epsilon^{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes\epsilon^{i_k}$ for some $A_{i_1\dots i_k}^{j_1\dots j_l}$. You need to verify that $A_{i_1\dots i_k}^{j_1\dots j_l} = F(\epsilon^{j_1},\dots,\epsilon^{j_l},e_{i_1},\dots,e_{i_k})$, so evaluate $F(\epsilon^{j_1},\dots,\epsilon^{j_l},e_{i_1},\dots,e_{i_k})$ instead.

Comment: I'm trying to get two birds with one stone. I haven't verified myself that $F = A_{i_1\dots i_k}^{j_1\dots j_l}e_{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{j_l}\otimes\epsilon^{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes\epsilon^{i_k}$ actually holds. I'm only taking it for granted as for now. That's why I would like to evaluate $F(b^1,\dots,b^l,a_1,\dots,a_k)$. @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: The set of elements of the form $e_{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{j_l}\otimes\epsilon^{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes\epsilon^{i_k}$ is a basis, so $F$ can be written as a linear combination of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up $k$ and $l$ several times. Also, where is it said that $b^i$ is both a covector and also a scalar component of the covector? It is just a covector! Its basis expansion is $b^i=b^i(e_j)\epsilon^j$, i.e the components of the covector $b^i$ relative to the basis $\{\epsilon^1,\dots,\epsilon^n\}$ of $V^*$ are the numbers $b^i(e_1),\dots, b^i(e_n)$, which if you feel so inclined, you can denote $b^i_{\,j}$.

Anyway, the basis for $T^k_l(V)=\underbrace{V^* \otimes \dots \otimes V^*}_{l} \otimes \underbrace{V \otimes \dots \otimes V}_{k}$ is given by the set
\begin{align}
B_{(k,l)}=\{\epsilon^{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes \epsilon^{i_l}\otimes e_{j_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{j_k}\,|\,\, i_1,\dots, i_l,j_1,\dots, j_k\in\{1,\dots, n\}\}.
\end{align}
Note the ordering and the indices (the $l$ covectors appear in the tensor product first, followed by the $k$ vectors). Given any $F\in T^k_l(V)$, this can be thought of as a multilinear map $F:\underbrace{V^*\times \cdots \times V^*}_{k}\times\underbrace{V\times \dots \times V}_{l}\to\Bbb{R}$. Note the $k$ and $l$ and where the $*$ appears. The claim now is that
\begin{align}
F&=F(\epsilon^{j_1},\dots, \epsilon^{j_k},e_{i_1},\dots, e_{i_l})\cdot\epsilon^{i_1}\otimes \cdots\otimes\epsilon^{i_1}\otimes e_{j_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{j_k}.
\end{align}

---

Anyway, I would suggest first writing out the proof in a few special cases such as $(k,l)\in\{(1,0), (0,1), (1,1),(1,2),(2,1)\}$, because the general case is just a zillion more indices.

Comment: How come the $k$ and $l$ are being switched when defining $F$? @peek-a-boo

Comment: @Darksi that's the definition. look at the lectures again. There is a more abstract-algebraic way of defining tensor products (using the universal property), and from there it really follows that things need to be switched around (because the universal property concerns itself with linear maps *out* of the tensor product). Anyway, this is just extra mumbo jumbo; for now you just need to learn the definition, and a few simple examples.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide one of the examples $(k,l)\in\{(1,0), (0,1), (1,1),(1,2),(2,1)\}$ so that I could get a feeling how to do the computations if it's not too much work for you? If I may ask one of $(1,1), (1,2)$ or $(2,1)$ as they already involve some playing around with the indices. @peek-a-boo

Comment: how about you show me your calculations? Also, such questions have been asked several times on the site, so look for similar questions. And if that doesn't help, rewatch the lectures (he also has another set of lectures for GR; (lecture 3), and watch that as well. I found that going over the same material several times helps). Finally, also pick up a textbook (e.g. Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds/Intro to differential geometry, vol 1, or John Lee's books).

Comment: this stuff **will** be confusing if this is your first encounter with them. And even now, I have to think long and hard about index placements (even though conceptually I know what I'm doing/ what I want to do) so I don't mess them up on paper, so the bottom line is it will take time, but you just have to grind through it until you learn the definitions (and make sure you learn/copy them correctly).

Comment: Okay let's see for $T^1_2(V) = V \otimes V^* \otimes V^*.$ For $F \in T^1_2(V)$ we have that $F: V^* \times V \times V \to \Bbb R$. Say the bases for $V$ and $V^*$ are same as in the question. Now $$B_{(1,2)}=\{\epsilon^{i_1}\otimes \epsilon^{i_2}\otimes e_{j_1}\,|\,\, i_1, i_2,j_1\in\{1,\dots, n\}\}.
$$ So one needs to verify that $F=F^{j_1}_{i_1,i_2}\epsilon^{i_1}\otimes \epsilon^{i_2}\otimes e_{j_1}$ where $F^{j_1}_{i_1,i_2}=F(\epsilon^{j_1}, e_{i_1}, e_{i_2})$. Picking vectors $a_1, a_2$ and covector $b^1$ I need to calculate $$F(b^1,a_1,a_2).$$

Comment: Now again I need to expand $b^1 = b^1(e_1)\epsilon^1 + \dots + b^1(e_n)\epsilon^n$ and $a_1 = c_1e_1 + \dots + c_ne_n$ and likewise $a_2 = d_1e_1 + \dots +  d_ne_n$. So $$F(b^1, a_1, a_2) = F(b^1(e_1)\epsilon^1 + \dots + b^1(e_n)\epsilon^n, c_1e_1 + \dots + c_ne_n, d_1e_1 + \dots d_ne_n). $$ I'm stuck here trying to use multilinearity to extract the coefficients from the sums. @peek-a-boo

Comment: ok, good. Using multilinearity, all those coefficients will come out of $F$. Next, note in particular that $c_i=\epsilon^i(a_1)$ and $d_i=\epsilon^i(a_2)$ (btw maybe now you'll notice why its better to have written the coefficients as $a_1=c^1e_1+\dots +c^ne_n$, and likewise, $a_2=d^1e_1+\dots +d^ne_n$). From here, using the definition of tensor product you can finish off.

Comment: So I'll get that $$F(b^1, a_1, a_2) = F(b^1(e_1)\epsilon^1 + \dots + b^1(e_n)\epsilon^n, c_1e_1 + \dots + c_ne_n, d_1e_1 + \dots d_ne_n)$$ equals $$b^1(e_1) \cdots b^1(e_n) c_1 \cdots c_n d_1\cdots d_nF(\epsilon^1 +  \dots + \epsilon^n, e_1 + \dots+ e_n, e_1 + \dots+ e_n)?$$ I think I'm making some mistake with $$F(\epsilon^1 +  \dots + \epsilon^n, e_1 + \dots+ e_n, e_1 + \dots+ e_n)$$ @peek-a-boo

Comment: you're not using multilinearity correctly. Whenever you get stuck on problems like this, always simplify the errors! Start with what linearity means. Next, what does bilinearity mean? Next, what does trilineairty mean? If necessary, assume $n=2$ for simplicity.

Comment: Okay so a bit easier using summation notation. We have that $$F(b^1, a_1, a_2) = F\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b^1(e_i)\epsilon^i, \sum_{j=1}^n c_je_j, \sum_{k=1}^n d_ke_k \right)$$ and now we can pull out the sums $$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^nb^1(e_i)c_jd_k F(\epsilon^i, e_j, e_k).$$ Now I should be able to finish off by the tensor product definition? @peek-a-boo

Comment: yes correct. Now, $b^1(e_i)c^jd^k=b^1(e_i)\epsilon^j(a_1)\epsilon^k(a_2)=\dots$ where $\dots$ is something involving tensor products. Use the definition here.

Comment: Is it that $$b^1(e_i)c_jd_k = b^1(e_i)\epsilon^j(a_1)\epsilon^k(a_2) = e_i \otimes \epsilon^j \otimes \epsilon^k(b^1,a_1,a_2)?$$ The definition says that if $T$ and $S$ are tensors then $(T \otimes S)(v_1, \dots, v_n, s_1, \dots, s_m) = T(v_1, \dots, v_n)S(s_1, \dots, s_m)$ so I need to use the fact that $e_i$ is a $(0,1)$ tensor and $\epsilon^j$ and $\epsilon^k$ $(1,0)$ tensors here? Is the action of $e_i$ just multiplication? @peek-a-boo

Comment: @Darksi $e_i$ is a $(1,0)$ tensor and $\epsilon$'s are $(0,1)$ tensors (again, you're mixing up things). Yes, $e_i\in V\cong V^{**}$ , so $e_i(\beta):=\beta(e_i)$ for all covectors $\beta\in V^*$. The action of $e_i$ on a covector is by definition evaluation of the covector on the vector because that's what the double-duality means. I'm sure he explains this in the elctures. You need to spend more time with the definitions.